# How to hide red underline of spellcheck without disabling spellcheck

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-spellcheck

Is there any way to hide the red underline of spellcheck errors in default android edittext. I don't want to disable the spellcheck or autocorrect.

I need to take a screenshot(getting bitmap from edittext) of edittext with content which may have spellcheck errors. And I don't want my screenshot to have red underlines of spellcheck. It should have only edittext content.

Please note I don't want to disable the spellcheck or auto correct.

Any ideas will be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> I don't want to disable the spellcheck or autocorrect

Having spellcheck checking but not marking typos is pretty much pointless.

> And I don't want my screenshot to have red underlines of spellcheck. It should have only edittext content.

Then take the screenshot as it is, load it into Gimp or Photoshop and iether do color replace on that red marks with background color or plain solid fill.

Comment: Hey Marcin,
Thanks for your response.
I have to show a preview of the edittext content before opening the full content. For that I need to take screenshot(by saying screenshot I mean converting view to bitmap) while closing. I just want to hide the red color alone which may have come while editing.
So all I asked was Is there any method like "setSpellcheckColorVisible(true)" is available?

Comment: I am not really understand your case here. What about screenshoting **other** edittext (invisible) where you will be just copying text from that one  you got now? In that case both can be configured differently and you can disable spellcheck on that invisible one without affecting your main edittext. Alternatively you can check EditText sources to see if you can easily tweak class behavior to match your needs  and if so, just create own view extending EditText and add your changes there